# how to install ffmpeg in cpanel

Tags: hosting, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I heard that most probably cpanel server dont have ffmpeg preconfigured in it. Can you explain a way to install it in cpanel.

Please if you can guide me through the installtion of ffmpeg in cpanel server in step by step process.

Can anyone please also give me links of other servers which have ffmpeg preconfigured and set to run.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a reasonably comprehensive guide, but my knowledge of the situation isn't good personally.  There are a few other tutorials but this would be good as a separate tutorial/perhaps wiki because it's quite a common question I hear asked by my hosting clients.

http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f15/how-install-ffmpeg-ffmpeg-php-mplayer-mencoder-flv2tool-lame-mp3-encoder-4893/

perhaps also

serverhostingsecrets.com/tutorials/cpanel-ffmpeg-howto/

Answer (score 0):

If you have CentoOS, RedHat or fedorra, you can install it using yum.
First add the dag repo.
http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B

```
rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS//rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel
```

Your can also install the mplayer and mencoder using yum from the dag repo

```
yum install mplayer mencoder
```